# solution of a ODE $dy/dx = ((y+a)(y+b) + x)/(y+b)^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my work, I derived an ODE of the following form

> $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(y+a)(y+b) + x}{(y+b)^2}$

where $a > 0$ and $b > 0$ are constants. I wonder if there is an analytical solution of this equation? Anyone can give a clue on how to solve it?

Comment: I tried a couple of the basic things e.g. exact, integrating factor etc.  It seemed pretty intractable.  Series methods would lead to very, very complicated recurrence relations, provided that the algebra was right.  

This isn't altogether surprising since this is a quadratic system in the plane, which are known to have very complicated behaviors (You can read the books by Perko, Andronov, and  Guckenheimer and Holmes to get a sense of how complicated the qualitative behavior can be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(y+a)(y+b) + x}{(y+b)^2}$$
Let $\quad Y(x)=\frac{1}{y+b}$
$$Y'=-Y^2+(b-a)Y^3-xY^4$$
This is an Abel's differential equation of the first kind :
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbelsDifferentialEquation.html

where $f_0(x)=0\:,\:f_1(x)=0\:,\:f_2(x)=-1\:,\:f_3(x)=b-a\:,\:f_4(x)=-x$

In the general case, the Abel's ODEs are unsolvable differential equations. The most likely, there is no closed form for the solutions. So, my answer is to recommend numerical methods for solving this kind of ODE.

Answer (score 2):

Let $r=y+b$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dr}{dx}=\dfrac{dy}{dx}$

$\therefore\dfrac{dr}{dx}=\dfrac{r(r+a-b)+x}{r^2}$

$(x+r(r+a-b))\dfrac{dx}{dr}=r^2$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $u=x+r(r+a-b)$ ,

Then $x=u-r(r+a-b)$

$\dfrac{dx}{dr}=\dfrac{du}{dr}-2r-a+b$

$\therefore u\left(\dfrac{du}{dr}-2r-a+b\right)=r^2$

$u\dfrac{du}{dr}-(2r+a-b)u=r^2$

$u\dfrac{du}{dr}=(2r+a-b)u+r^2$

Let $s=r+\dfrac{a-b}{2}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dr}=\dfrac{du}{ds}\dfrac{ds}{dr}=\dfrac{du}{ds}$

$\therefore u\dfrac{du}{ds}=2su+\left(s-\dfrac{a-b}{2}\right)^2$

$u\dfrac{du}{ds}=2su+s^2-(a-b)s+\dfrac{(a-b)^2}{4}$

Let $t=s^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{ds}=\dfrac{du}{dt}\dfrac{dt}{ds}=2s\dfrac{du}{dt}$

$\therefore2su\dfrac{du}{dt}=2su+s^2-(a-b)s+\dfrac{(a-b)^2}{4}$

$u\dfrac{du}{dt}=u+\dfrac{s}{2}-\dfrac{a-b}{2}+\dfrac{(a-b)^2}{8s}$

$u\dfrac{du}{dt}=u\pm\dfrac{\sqrt t}{2}-\dfrac{a-b}{2}\pm\dfrac{(a-b)^2}{8\sqrt t}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind in the canonical form.

Please follow the method in https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1503/1503.05929.pdf

For the special case $a-b=-1$ , this exactly belongs to the ODE of the form http://science.fire.ustc.edu.cn/download/download1/book%5Cmathematics%5CHandbook%20of%20Exact%20Solutions%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20EquationsSecond%20Edition%5Cc2972_fm.pdf#page=137.

WLOG, just consider $u\dfrac{du}{dt}=u+\dfrac{\sqrt t}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{8\sqrt t}$ ,

The general solution is $\begin{cases}t=\dfrac{(C_1\tau J_1(\tau)+C_2\tau Y_1(\tau)+C_1J_0(\tau)+C_2Y_0(\tau))^2}{4(C_1J_0(\tau)+C_2Y_0(\tau))^2}\\u=\dfrac{\tau^2((C_1J_1(\tau)+C_2Y_1(\tau))^2\pm(C_1J_0(\tau)+C_2Y_0(\tau))^2)}{4(C_1J_0(\tau)+C_2Y_0(\tau))^2}\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}\left(r-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2=\dfrac{(C_1\tau J_1(\tau)+C_2\tau Y_1(\tau)+C_1J_0(\tau)+C_2Y_0(\tau))^2}{4(C_1J_0(\tau)+C_2Y_0(\tau))^2}\\x+r(r-1)=\dfrac{\tau^2((C_1J_1(\tau)+C_2Y_1(\tau))^2\pm(C_1J_0(\tau)+C_2Y_0(\tau))^2)}{4(C_1J_0(\tau)+C_2Y_0(\tau))^2}\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}\left(y+b-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2=\dfrac{(C_1\tau J_1(\tau)+C_2\tau Y_1(\tau)+C_1J_0(\tau)+C_2Y_0(\tau))^2}{4(C_1J_0(\tau)+C_2Y_0(\tau))^2}\\x+(y+b)(y+b-1)=\dfrac{\tau^2((C_1J_1(\tau)+C_2Y_1(\tau))^2\pm(C_1J_0(\tau)+C_2Y_0(\tau))^2)}{4(C_1J_0(\tau)+C_2Y_0(\tau))^2}\end{cases}$